# Converting JSON schema with nested and repeated field to DDL

Tags: google-bigquery

I am considering converting existing JSON table schema with 200+ colums with repeated and deeply nested data strucute to DDL

Does BigQuery provide an option to see DDL CREATE TABLE statement for existing table ?

MySQL for instance support

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name
```

Comment: Beside storing table definition, I have been also using JSON schema as part of our e2e  testing workflow, so it would be nice fully switch to SQL,

Comment: I don't think there is a nice way to do this aside from translating the JSON to the standard SQL type system. You may want to star the [feature request for INFORMATION_SCHEMA](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35906063) though, since that would be a way to get a list of columns and their types.

Comment: just started it,